Docker has an error when starting a container, I don't understand
I need to connect Docker with Azure but the container is not workingw
(HTTP code 500) server error - Ports are not available: exposing port TCP 0.0.0.0:1533 -> 0.0.0.0:0: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:1533: bind: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.
I wrote the problem to chatGPT and he told me to change the port number. I tried changing it but it didn't help

Without any details on what your container is doing or how you started it, it's hard t say more.  The linked question has a number of suggestions, largely focusing on the winnat service, but also a more detailed explanation of the message.

are you using EXPOSE 80 in docker file? so it run on localhost:80. it default port in docker
